# Look up value from array in another array, and then match a second value Google Apps Script Javascript JSON API

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm importing data from my crm Pipedrive into Google sheets using Google Apps Script. This is part of a larger process but I'm at an impasse with this section of the script. I need to return a value by matching two parts of one array to another array.

First I pull all deal fields, which returns custom field keys and their id/label pairs. Here's a simplified output example:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12500,
      "key": "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8",
      "name": "Lead Type",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Expired",
          "id": 28
        },
        {
          "label": "Sale",
          "id": 29
        },
        {
          "label": "Rent",
          "id": 30
        },
        {
          "label": "Other",
          "id": 31
        }
      ],
      "mandatory_flag": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I have separate info from a specific deal that includes an id. I need to match the below id `28` to the above array and return the label `Expired`:
`var leadType = dealresponse.data["c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8"];`
which returns `28`
I don't know what '28' means so that's why I need to match it to the label Expired.
The dealFields array is long, maybe 50 or 100 of the above array objects. And there are around 10 custom deal field keys where I will have to return the label base on matching the key and id. I think I have to loop each key and id to return the label. But not sure of the optimum way to do this and save on processing power.

I tried:

```
for (var i in dealFieldsresponse) {
    if (dealFieldsresponse[i].data.key == "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8") {
      for (var j in dealFieldsresponse[j]) {
         if (dealFieldsresponse[j].id == "28") {
           Logger.log(dealFieldsresponse[j].label);
         }
      }
    }
}
```

It's not working. I'm new at javascript and programming in general so this is my best guess and I appreciate any insights.

Edit: here's a bigger chunk of code that I have to work with:

```
// Get deal fields data
  var dealFieldsurl = URL +'/v1/dealFields?api_token='+ API_TOKEN;
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "contentType": "application/json",
  };
  var dealFieldsresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dealFieldsurl, options);
  dealFieldsresponse = JSON.parse(dealFieldsresponse.getContentText());

  
  
  // Get deal data
  var dealurl = URL +'/v1/deals/' + dealId + '?api_token='+ API_TOKEN;
  var options = {
    "method": "get",    
    "contentType": "application/json",
  };
  var dealresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dealurl, options);
  dealresponse = JSON.parse(dealresponse.getContentText());

  
 
  var propertyAddress = dealresponse.data["9bd1d8c4f07f5795fd8bffb16f3b63c6547d7d3a"];
  var leadType = dealresponse.data["c4ecbe01c3494d1be52432f4a3194ede3a50c0f8"];
      
  var dealType = dealresponse.data["a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e"];
  var dealSource = dealresponse.data["d76fa2d6f8454a51f7d64d981cd9320877bc2ea0"];
  var marketingFor = dealresponse.data["58cb55090b55652b7f89a8b44074682d874c548a"];
  var dateListedOnMarket = dealresponse.data["aa49c7b95a7d151bec4c2d936f6ab40d0caea43c"];
  var dateTakenOffMarket = dealresponse.data["660c1250b0a641a10ff9121c2df124ff89c13052"];
  var askingPrice = dealresponse.data["1de94dbf589fda7a3a3248662cd24f03d512a961"];
```

And the `dealFieldsresponse` variable stores an array with many objects containing arrays. Here are two primary objects, as you can see each has a `key` and then `options`. I need to match the key and then find the `id` within options for each `key`

```
{
"id": 12500,
"key": "c4ecbe01c3494d1be52432f4a3194ede3a50c0f8",
"name": "Lead Type",
"order_nr": 64,
"field_type": "set",
"add_time": "2020-08-20 19:33:22",
"update_time": "2020-08-20 19:33:22",
"last_updated_by_user_id": 11678191,
"active_flag": true,
"edit_flag": true,
"index_visible_flag": true,
"details_visible_flag": true,
"add_visible_flag": true,
"important_flag": true,
"bulk_edit_allowed": true,
"searchable_flag": false,
"filtering_allowed": true,
"sortable_flag": true,
"options": [
{
"label": "Expired",
"id": 28
},
{
"label": "Sale",
"id": 29
},
{
"label": "Rent",
"id": 30
},
{
"label": "Other",
"id": 31
}
],
"mandatory_flag": false
},
{
"id": 12502,
"key": "a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e",
"name": "Deal Type",
"order_nr": 65,
"field_type": "set",
"add_time": "2020-08-20 19:57:12",
"update_time": "2020-08-20 19:57:12",
"last_updated_by_user_id": 11678191,
"active_flag": true,
"edit_flag": true,
"index_visible_flag": true,
"details_visible_flag": true,
"add_visible_flag": true,
"important_flag": true,
"bulk_edit_allowed": true,
"searchable_flag": false,
"filtering_allowed": true,
"sortable_flag": true,
"options": [
{
"label": "Lease",
"id": 37
},
{
"label": "Financing",
"id": 38
},
{
"label": "Assign",
"id": 39
},
{
"label": "ST",
"id": 40
},
{
"label": "Other (see notes)",
"id": 41
}
],
"mandatory_flag": false
},
```

Edit 2: how do I return the labels for multiple ids?

```
const obj = {
  "a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e": {id: 37,38}, "58cb55090b55652b7f89a8b44074682d874c548a": {id: 44,45},
"2ec54cce0d091b69b1fd1a245c7aad02b57cadb8": {id: 126},
"fab84c732295022ecd7bdf58892a62cb4d8ecf24": {id: 50,52,54}, 
};
```

For example, I'd want the first to return `red, blue` as a string, and the second to return `green, orange` as a string. Assuming the labels that match the `id`s are colors. The third one only has one `id`, but the fourth one has three. How do I account for this? And I'd like my output to be some kind of array where I can then say search `key` `a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e` and return value `red, blue` as a string

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the result value you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm surprised that your question was updated. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your updated question. But I could understand that my answer was not suitable for your updated question. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, can I ask you about what you want to do for your updated question?

Comment: I think your answer is good and it worked for one instance - in other words, one key searching. My question is, is there a way to scale it bigger because there are multiple keys (each with an id needed to return a label) to search? For example, say I have `key` `c4ecbe01c3494d1be52432f4a3194ede3a50c0f8` and `id` `28` to search as well as `key` `a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e` and `id` `37`? The `id` `37` is only output from the above so I can't set that in advanced but I can make it a variable I suppose. The return I'm looking for are the labels `Expired` and `Lease`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your updated question, I cannot understand whether `key` is required to be corresponding to `id`. For example, when the key is `c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8`, you want to retrieve the value of `lavel` of the id `28`. When the key is other value, you want to retrieve the value of `lavel` of the id `28`? You want to use the same id?

Comment: I noticed that your comment has been updated. By this, I could understand about your goal. Can you give me a time to update my answer?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for what you've explain to me so far

Comment: Ok so I know the `key` in advanced - it is a fixed value. I then do a get request, and using the `key` `c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8`, it returns an `id` of let's say `28`. Then what I need to do is take the `key` and the `id` and use them return real value I want, which is the `label`, which is `Expired` in this example

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the result value you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of `label` using `key` and `id` from the JSON object in your question using Google Apps Script.

  - As a sample situation, you want to retrieve the value of `"label": "Expired"` using `"key": "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8"` and `"id": 28`.
- The JSON object has the arrays of `data` and `options`. Both arrays have the several elements.

#### Modification points:

- If `dealFieldsresponse` is the JSON object in your question, `dealFieldsresponse.data` and `dealFieldsresponse.data[].options` are 1 dimensional array. When you want to retrieve the value of `key` and `id`, it is required to loop those arrays.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const searchKey = "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8";  // Please set the value of key.
const searchId = 28;  // Please set the value of id.
  
const dealFieldsresponse = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12500,
      "key": "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8",
      "name": "Lead Type",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Expired",
          "id": 28
        },
        {
          "label": "FSBO",
          "id": 29
        },
        {
          "label": "FRBO",
          "id": 30
        },
        {
          "label": "Other",
          "id": 31
        }
      ],
      "mandatory_flag": false
    }
  ]
};
  
const data = dealFieldsresponse.data;
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].key == searchKey) {
    const options = data[i].options;
    for (let j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
      if (options[j].id.toString() == searchId.toString()) {
        // Logger.log(options[j].label);
        console.log(options[j].label);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Other sample:

As other sample script, how about the following script? In this sample, the result values are put in an array.

```js
const searchKey = "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8";  // Please set the value of key.
const searchId = 28;  // Please set the value of id.
  
const dealFieldsresponse = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12500,
      "key": "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8",
      "name": "Lead Type",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Expired",
          "id": 28
        },
        {
          "label": "FSBO",
          "id": 29
        },
        {
          "label": "FRBO",
          "id": 30
        },
        {
          "label": "Other",
          "id": 31
        }
      ],
      "mandatory_flag": false
    }
  ]
};

const res = dealFieldsresponse.data.reduce((ar, {key, options}) => {
  if (key == searchKey) {
    options.forEach(({id, label}) => {
      if (id == searchId) ar.push(label);
    });
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
console.log(res)
```

### Added:

When you want to retrieve the multiple values using the multiple `key` and `id`, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, the key `c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8` and id `28` and the key `a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e` and id `37` are searched and the values of `label` are retrieved.

```js
const obj = {
  "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8": {id: 28},
  "a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e": {id: 37}
};  // Please set the key and id you want to search.
  
const dealFieldsresponse = {
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 12500,
      "key": "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8",
      "name": "Lead Type",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Expired",
          "id": 28
        },
        {
          "label": "FSBO",
          "id": 29
        },
        {
          "label": "FRBO",
          "id": 30
        },
        {
          "label": "Other",
          "id": 31
        }
      ],
      "mandatory_flag": false
    }
  ]
};

dealFieldsresponse.data.forEach(({key, options}) => {
  if (obj[key]) {
    options.forEach(({id, label}) => {
      if (id == obj[key].id) obj[key].label = label;
    });
  }
});
console.log(obj)
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
{
  "c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8":{"id":28,"label":"Expired"},
  "a4269fb4730cf7fd1787752be94eacbc4b0de24e":{"id":37}
}
```

- At above sample JSON object, the label of the key `c4ecbe01c34994ede3a50c0f8` and id `28` is retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you've understood what I want to do. This makes sense what you're saying but I actually need to incorporate this into a larger script. First I do a GET request for several of these fields. Then the result is the `id` and then I need to feed that into the search to loop and find the label. I've edited the above code to show you what my script looks like

Comment: @823g4n8901 Thank you for replying. I'm surprised that your question was updated. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your updated question. But I could understand that my answer was not suitable for your updated question. So I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, can I ask you about what you want to do for your updated question?

Comment: Some of my keys contain multiple ids - I would like to look up the return the label for each id and return all the labels as a string. I've edited the above

Comment: @823g4n8901 About your updated question, I noticed that you had already posted it as [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64543285), and an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. By the way, in the current stage, there are 2 same questions in your questions. So please remove the additional question of `Edit 2: how do I return the labels for multiple ids?`. Because when your initial question is changed, other users who see your question are confused. By the way, `{id: 50,52,54}` is not correct for JSON object. Please be careful this.