# Look up values in an array using looping forEach Google Apps Script Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an object that looks like the following {key: id numbers}

```
var obj = {
  "c4ecb": {id: [3]},
  "a4269": {id: [34,36]},
  "d76fa": {id: [54,55,60,61]},
  "58cb5": {id: [67]}
}
```

How do I loop each above `id` in the following array, and return the `label`?

```
var response = 
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "c4ecb",
          "name": "fruits",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "strawberry",
              "id": 3
            },
            {
              "label": "apple",
              "id": 4
            },
            {
              "label": "pineapple",
              "id": 5
            },
            {
              "label": "Other",
              "id": 31
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "a4269",
          "name": "vegetables",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "lettuce",
              "id": 34
            },
            {
              "label": "cucumber",
              "id": 35
            },
            {
              "label": "radish",
              "id": 36
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "d76fa",
          "name": "pasta",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "spaghetti",
              "id": 54
            },
            {
              "label": "rigatoni",
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "label": "linguine",
              "id": 56
            },
            {
              "label": "lasagna",
              "id": 60
            },
            {
              "label": "fettuccine",
              "id": 61
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
```

Finally, what I want to do is look up the key and return a string of id values.
For example, input `c4ecb` and output `strawberry`. Input `a4269` and output `lettuce, radish`. Input `d76fa` and output "`spaghetti, rigatoni, lasagna, fettuccine`"

I think to join the multiple labels output into one string I could use something like

```
array.data.vegetables.map(vegetables => vegetables.value).join(', ')].toString();
```

So in the end I want to have something like

```
var fruits = [some code that outputs "strawberry"];
var vegetables = [some code that outputs "lettuce, radish"];
var pasta = [some code that outputs "spaghetti, rigatoni, lasagna, fettuccine"];
```

What I've tried so far:
The following loop will return the `id` only if there is one `id` to be called for: e.g. only in case one where `{id: 3}` but returns null in cases like `{id: 34,36}` (because it's looking for '`34,36`' in `id`, which doesn't exist - I need to look for each one individually.

```
response.data.forEach(({key, options}) => {
  if (obj[key]) {
    options.forEach(({id, label}) => {
      if (id == obj[key].id) obj[key].label = label;
    });
  }
});
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Your `obj` is not valid JSON. I assume that's part of the problem, but maybe I misunderstand google apps script. I was going to say you should `.split(",")` the IDs and do a lookup for each that you find.

Comment: `"a4269": {id: 34,36},//if id is a string then "id":"34,36" if it is an array then it should be "id":[34,36]`

Comment: I did change the ids to an array above. so instead of "id": "34,36" it's now "id": [34,36]. Then I need to return an array like [{"a4269": {label: [lettuce, radish]}}, {"d76fa": {label: [spaghetti, rigatoni, lasagna, fettuccine]}}, ...] then I need have var vegetables = return 'lettuce, radish', then var pasta = return 'spaghetti, rigatoni, lasagna, fetuccine' etc, which I don't know how to approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the `response` object to focus on the category that matches the `id`.
Map over the `options` array and select the items which appear in `obj[id]`.
Finally convert the filtered results to a string.

See `filteredLabelsAsString()` function below for implementation.

```js
var obj = {
  "c4ecb": {"id": [3]},
  "a4269": {"id": [34,36]},
  "d76fa": {"id": [54,55,60,61]},
  "58cb5": {"id": [67]}
}

var response = 
    [{
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "c4ecb",
          "name": "fruits",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "strawberry",
              "id": 3
            },
            {
              "label": "apple",
              "id": 4
            },
            {
              "label": "pineapple",
              "id": 5
            },
            {
              "label": "Other",
              "id": 31
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "a4269",
          "name": "vegetables",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "lettuce",
              "id": 34
            },
            {
              "label": "cucumber",
              "id": 35
            },
            {
              "label": "radish",
              "id": 36
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
        {
          "key": "d76fa",
          "name": "pasta",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "spaghetti",
              "id": 54
            },
            {
              "label": "rigatoni",
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "label": "linguine",
              "id": 56
            },
            {
              "label": "lasagna",
              "id": 60
            },
            {
              "label": "fettuccine",
              "id": 61
            }
          ],
        }
      ]
    }];
 
 
 function filteredLabelsAsString(obj_key, obj, content=response) {
    // sanity check: obj must contain obj_key
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {
        return content.filter((item) => {
            // filter content using value of obj_key
            return item.data[0].key == obj_key;
        }).map((item) => {
            // item : { success: true, data: [] }
            // map over options array
            return item.data[0].options.map((opt) => {
                // option : {id, label}
                // return the label if the id is in the obj object's list
                if (obj[item.data[0].key].id.includes(opt.id))
                    return opt.label;
            }).filter((label) => {
                // filter out empty items
                return label !== undefined;
            });
        }).join(",");
    }
    // if obj does not contain obj_key return empty string
    return "";
}

console.log("fruits: " + filteredLabelsAsString("c4ecb", obj));

console.log("vegetables: " + filteredLabelsAsString("a4269", obj));

console.log("pasta: " + filteredLabelsAsString("d76fa", obj));
```

Comment: Thanks for the above filter. I can run the code snippet and see the results log perfectly. When I paste this into google apps script, however, I'm getting an error: `Cannot convert undefined or null to object (line 94)`, which is `if Object.keys(obj).includes(obj_key)) {` I don't know why it's coming up as null. I'm not sure if the `content = response` is referencing the above response variable correctly that's why it's returning null